# How to make table hidden in all email clients

Tags: html, css, email-client, email-templates

I have written this way pass div in email html body using C# code:

```
  <div style='display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;
       color:transparent; height:0; width:0; mso-hide:all; line-height:0px; 
            font-size:0px'>DATA'</div>
```

Comment: You're talking about a table but showing a div. I assume the table is inside the div? Could you supply the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can not effectively *hide* an element in Gmail but you can *zero it out*.

The trick is to leverage the difference between Gmail and other email clients.  This difference is the fact that Gmail will not read or render any styling other than inline styles.  Any CSS written within `<style></style>` tags will be ignored.

This is the case only for Gmail so we can use this difference to our advantage by setting the inline styling of the element we wish to hide to zero values, and in the `<style></style>` block we set the appropriate values for the element so all clients OTHER than Gmail will render the element appropriately.

```
<style>
*[class=mobile] {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) { 
    *[class=mobile] {
        display:block !important;
        width:auto !important;
        max-height:inherit !important;
        overflow:visible !important;
        float:none !important;
    }

    *[class="block"] {
        display:block !important;
        padding:5px;
    }
}
</style>

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td class="mobile" style="width:0;max-height:0;overflow: hidden;">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150" alt="" border=0 width="100%" style="display:block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

*The addition of the `mso` code in the example below is for the added support of Outlook.*

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, you are trying to hide the table which resides inside the div. and it is creating problem in gmail and outlook clients.

In that case applysame style to table also it will solve your problem, if not please share more info regarding problem.

```
<div style='display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;
   color:transparent; height:0; width:0; mso-hide:all; line-height:0px; 
        font-size:0px'><table style='display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;
   color:transparent; height:0; width:0; mso-hide:all; line-height:0px; 
        font-size:0px'><tr><td>DATA</td></tr></table></div>
```